# Nesting arrays into NSDictionary object (Objective-C)

Tags: cocoa, nested, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

I would like to define tasks using NSDictionary, which I'd like to save in a plist file (I didn't have much luck with Core Data so far), but got stuck at two points:

-- When using `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` I can change the data type to number or boolean, using NSDate's `numberWithInt:` and `numberWithBool:` methods, respectively. I can't seem to find the method to change the type to date though. I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation.

-- The second problem I ran into was with the nested arrays. How can I add them to the dictionary?

I have uploaded a picture to [here](https://skitch.com/antal/r8psx/task-structure) of what I am trying to achieve. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `NSNumber`'s `+numberWithInt:` and `+numberWithBool:` methods, not `NSDate`?  It's NSNumber that defines those methods.

To convert a number to a date, it really depends on what the number is.  If it's a UNIX timestamp, then `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:theTimestampInSeconds]`.

As for adding `NSArray` objects to a dictionary:

```
[yourDictionary setObject:yourArray forKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

You'll have to post some code if you need more help as your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `NSNumber`. As for the nested array, I have tried it (again?) the way you suggested, and it worked! It didn't seem to do the trick before.

Comment: If your array happened to be nil before (such as when you have not yet initialized it) then you'd get a runtime error since you can't store nil in a dictionary.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

for the date you can also use `numberWithInt:` and the `timeIntervalSince1970` method of NSDate to get a Timestamp. Theres also a Constructor for that Timestamp.

For nested Arrays you can simply add NSArray Objects in the Dictonary.

Answer (score -1):

Your plist should pick up the date format and store it using the Date type, so you can just ploug in the `NSDate`.

```
[plist setObject:theDate forKey:@"theDateKey"];
```

To save an array to your dictionary, use something like:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"One", @"2", @"Two"];
```

Comment: That second example is not an array, and will actually crash.