# NSDictionary containing an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, data-structures, dictionary

I am very new to Objective-C and haven't had a lot of experience with C so please excuse my ignorance. My question is this, is it possible to add an Array to a Dictionary? Here is what I'd do in Python, and it's very convenient:

```
if 'mykey' not in mydictionary:
    mydictionary['mykey']=[] # init an empty list for 'mykey'
mydictionary['mykey'].append('someitem')
```

I want something like this, that works:

```
NSMutableDictionary *matchDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *matchArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 

while (blah):
    [matchDict setObject: [matchArray addObject: myItem] forKey: myKey];
```

I looked everywhere with no luck, just about to give up. Any feedback will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really different from what you did in python.

```
NSMutableDictionary *matchDict = ...
NSMutableArray *matchArray = ...
[matchDict setObject:matchArray forKey:someKey];
// This is same as: mydictionary['mykey']=[]


// 'matchArray' is still a valid pointer so..
[matchArray addObject:someObj];

// or later if 'matchArray' were no longer in scope 
// it would look like this:

NSMutableArray* arrayForKey = [matchDict objectForKey:someKey];
[arrayForKey addObject:someObj];

// or more simply:
[[matchDict objectForKey:someKey] addObject:someObj];

// this is same as: mydictionary['mykey'].append('someitem')
```

*edit*

So if you need to add arrays for more than one key you might do this:

Given an array of two keys:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key0",@"key1", nil];
```

And a dictionary...

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[keys count]];
```

Here is how you could create an array for each key:

```
for (id key in keys) {

    // Create a new array each time...

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    // and insert into dictionary as value for this key

    [dict setObject:array forKey:key];
}
```

Hopefully that gives you the idea.

Comment: If Firoze's answer is what you were after, you should accept it.

Comment: I tried this code and it's does add an array, but it's no where near the same as Python. If I have four values with a key of one and two other values with a key of two I'd end up with: {1:['one','two','three','four'], 2: ['one','two'} using Python. The above will give me {1:['one','two','three','four'],2:['one','two','three','four']} Python uses the key to append like a filter.

Comment: It sounds like you just added the same array twice. You need to create a new array for each key.

Comment: @Firoze I tried to create a new array for each unique key, but I'm just not getting how to word it properly. Your code is correct, I'm just lost on how to assign a new array to a unique key.

Comment: @Firoze Thanks again for your help. I think I need to create an empty array for each unique key so the values associated for that key get populated to the dictionary properly without pointer issues, or simply populating a single array with all values under every key in the dict. This is all dynamic so I really don't know what key or value I'm getting back in the loop. Python is two lines, and I think I missed a line in my original question: "if key not in dict: dict[key]=[]" then every time I get a value associated with that key it simply appends to the proper key in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
    [matchDict setObject:matchArray forKey:@"myKey"];
```

I had to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582791/nesting-arrays-into-nsdictionary-object-objective-c) myself 3 months ago, so don't worry too much about asking ;)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, having some trouble figuring this out. Just get an error or an empty dictionary.

Comment: @Mohawke The snippets we have posted here should definitely work, so your problem might be with another part of your code. If you could upload it to somewhere I'd be happy to review it and help you make it work.

Comment: Basically I'm looping through the file system and calculating the MD5 hash for each file. If a hash matches I have a duplicate file. For each hash I wanted to append the file path for the matching hashes making the hash the key and the matches the array.[objective-c code](http://www.darkartistry.com/content/view/246/38/) I'm a Python programmer and just starting with Objective-C and haven't had much problems until this. [Python code](http://www.darkartistry.com/content/view/242/41/). I think Python has spoiled me. I tried the examples provided, but they are not working for me.

Comment: @Mohawke Looking at your code, I think you assume that if you insert a new value for the same key, it would become an array with both values. In Obj-C it simply overwrites the old value. If you have a match, you should create a new array, add the new match to it, and overwrite the existing key with the new dictionary.

Comment: Yes, like I said, Python spoiled me ;) I actually understand that I can't simply populate an array based on the key in the dictionary, but I also don't understand how to achieve my goal syntactically to get an array of items under it's relevant key. I tried the examples, and several other ideas, and it's just not working. I do appreciate your, and Firoze's, assistance. I'm working through a book now so maybe I'll get some ideas as I learn. It seems silly I need two dictionaries and an array to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it I ended up solving the problem. If you want to populate an array for each key dynamically, you do it like this:

```
While (something)
{
    // check if key is already in dict.
    if ([_matchesDictionary objectForKey: hashKey]) 
        {
            // pull existing array from dict and add new entry to array for said key.
            NSMutableArray *keyArray = [_matchesDictionary objectForKey: hashKey];
            [keyArray addObject: newPath];

            // put the array back into the dict for said key.
            [_matchesDictionary setObject: keyArray forKey: hashKey];

     } else {

            // create new array, assign empty array to said key in dict.
            NSMutableArray *keyArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [keyArray addObject: newPath];
            [_matchesDictionary setObject: keyArray forKey: hashKey];

     } 

}
```

This will yield {('value1',value2',etc...) : 'somekey'}

Thanks @Antal and @Firoze for all the help, you helped me to work it out. Just needed to stop thinking "Python". If either of you see any issue or a better implementation let me know.