# Adding Arrays as key & value in a dictionary type in iOS9 swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, ios9, plist

I am creating a plist in which I want to save a certain data. I have a dictionary which I need to write in the file. The dictionary has a name array for values and a key array bfor keys. But I dont have the idea of where I am doing wrong but my code is not working.

```
let namearray = [self.usernametextfield.text,self.passwordtextfield.text]
        let keyarray = ["username","password"]
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict.setObject(namearray as! AnyObject, forKey: keyarray) // I am having problem in this line of how to add arrays to dictionary. 
        dict .writeToFile(plistfinalpath, atomically: true)
```

So can any one suggest how to add arrays as keys and values in a dictionary. Please rectify my code.

Comment: From [aaisataev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5400375/aaisataev): You can rewrite it in swift - [NSDictionary containing an NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526941/nsdictionary-containing-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 1):

you are not able to use an array as a key

i am not sure, what do you need exactly, but probably something like

```
import Foundation
let namearray = ["name","pswd"]
let keyarray = ["username","password"]
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setObject(namearray[0], forKey: keyarray[0])
dict.setObject(namearray[1], forKey: keyarray[1])
// gives you

dump(dict)
/*
▿ 2 key/value pairs
▿ [0]: (2 elements)
▿ .0: username #0
▿ NSMutableString: username
▿ NSString: username
- NSObject: username
- .1: name
▿ [1]: (2 elements)
▿ .0: password #1
▿ NSMutableString: password
▿ NSString: password
- NSObject: password
- .1: pswd
*/
```

OK, it seems, that you want to add an array to dictionary ...

```
import Foundation
let namearray = ["name","pswd"]
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setObject(namearray, forKey: "user1")
// gives you

dump(dict)
/*
▿ 1 key/value pair
▿ [0]: (2 elements)
▿ .0: user1 #0
▿ NSMutableString: user1
▿ NSString: user1
- NSObject: user1
▿ .1: 2 elements
- [0]: name
- [1]: pswd
*/
```

Comment: Ok you have gvn grt answers in past to my questions. Tx. Here I want that whenever user enters username and password it would be saved  in plist path. In obj c I was adding username,password to value array and after then i added it to a dictionary with corresponding key array. So is it possible in swift.

Comment: yes, you can add an array to dictionary. see my example above. next you can save it to plist, as you tried before. i choose a key "user1", it is up to you, what will be your key. the key must be NSCopying compatible, thats all

Comment: the key must not be an array, at all. it must be an value, conforming NSCopying ( the same for swift as for Objective C)

Comment: i checked again you notes to my answer. it seem, that you want save in dictionary a username value for key username and password value for key password. in that case my first example is exactly, what do you want.

Comment: if you have a working Objective C code, update your question, we can than 'translate' your code to swift

Comment: @ user3441734 oh if we want to add entire array to a dictionary,can we do that because you are adding the particular object at that index? So can we do that?

Comment: @G.Abhisek yes, exactly. the value can be any kind of value, including an Array, or another Dictionary ...(as you can see in my last example. the value stored in the dictionary is an Array